# jquery работа с блоками одного класса

Tags: jquery

У меня с помощью метода append добавляется несколько блоков уведомлений, которые должны скрываться после 5 секунд. Я использую следующий код.

```
 setTimeout(function() { 
     $(".good").hide('slow'); }, 5000);
 })
```

Html код

```
<div class="push">
<div class="good">Первое уведомление</div>
<div class="good">Второе уведомление</div>
<div class="good">Третье уведомление</div>
</div>
```

При этом появляются уведомления в разное время, но скрываются одновременно. Нужно чтобы каждый элемент скрывался в своё время (через свои 5 секунд).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let newBlock = $('<div class="good"></div>').text('Второе уведомление').appendTo($('.push')); 
setTimeout(function(block) { block.hide('slow'); }, 5000, newBlock);
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Не могли бы вы чуть объяснить? Как это работает)

Comment: @ИльяКузнецов 1. Создается новый блок `newBlock ` - https://api.jquery.com/appendto/. 2. Этот блок передается в качестве параметра в функцию таймера - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout.

Comment: Спасибо вам. Буду знать)

Comment: @ИльяКузнецов Пожалуйста. Успехов!